# How to add circuit after paragarph?

Tags: paragraphs, circuitikz

I'm a newbie.
I was trying to draw circuits in latex. After drawing a circuit I have written a section.In this section, while drawing circuit it is coming in the previous section after the first circuit.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possibly you are using a `figure` environment, that happens to be a "floating" environment ... See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text PS: Ask me to delete the comment if this is  not the problem, but then, add a MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: Yeah I'm doing it as a figure, as I need to mention that circuit in the list of figures

Comment: Both solutions of the link will work for you then. Try them and ask to close your question as a dupplicate

Comment: Did you solved it? You had to add an `H`...

Comment: I have flagged the question, thank you for the link

Comment: Nice... Welcome.